# Recreate Scheme SQL

Tags: phpmyadmin

i need some help i download a script from a website and i want to test it but this script SQL dump file is missing. all i did was upload it to my localhost and install the script however i'm having issue completing the installation.

one of the users mention "It's checking the api_license and getting the fresh db queries :/ we need to know the username and password to get that fresh queries. If anyone have sql dump, share!"

admin reply

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `download` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `bits` varchar(100)
>   DEFAULT NULL, `duration` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, `milisec` int(10)
>   unsigned DEFAULT NULL, `uploader` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL, `cover`
>   varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `cover_large` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `vid_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `like` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `size` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `search` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, `tag` text, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Try to recreate scheme and get working version with this sql.

my question is do you guys know what does he mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to recreate scheme and get working version with this sql.

I think he meant to create this schema in mysql and maybe populate based on sensible data ? Nobody can really comment until you post more details about the context.

```
CREATE TABLE `download` (
    `id` INT (10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`title` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`bits` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`duration` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`milisec` INT (10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
    ,`uploader` VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`cover` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`cover_large` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`vid_id` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`like` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`size` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;



    CREATE TABLE`search` (
    `id` INT (10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`tag` TEXT
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```